# Mod_Rewrite, search for non-existing files in a different folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a templates system in which I use images and other kinds of files, so here is a sample of a few templates and their images

```
/templates/template1/images/image1.jpg
/templates/template1/images/header/red/new/image1.jpg
/templates/template1/image2.jpg
/templates/template2/images/image2.jpg
/templates/template2/image2.jpg
```

Now, some times the templates miss an image or a file, in those cases I want to redirect the user to the "default" template, while keeping the rest of the url.

So for the examples given, if the image is not found the user should be redirected to

```
/templates/default/images/image1.jpg
/templates/default/images/header/red/new/image1.jpg
/templates/default/image2.jpg
/templates/default/images/image2.jpg
/templates/default/image2.jpg
```

This is my attempt at making this work, it's defined in the virtual host file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/default/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/templates/(.*)/(.*) /templates/default/$2 [R]
```

this right now

redirects     /templates/template1/images/image1.jpg to     /templates/default/image1.jpg and then throws a 500 error.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Any details in the Apache error log about that 500 error?

Comment: Try adding `$` to `^/templates/(.*)/(.*)` to make `^/templates/(.*)/(.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting the 500, but the ReqriteRule will have problems with multiple sub-directories because of the greediness of the first `.*`.

Consider the request for /templates/template1/images/header/red/new/image1.jpg.  If this file *does not exist* then in `^/templates/(.*)/(.*)`, the first `(.*)` will match all of "template1/images/header/red/new" and the second (.*) will match "image1.jpg" and so you'll get redirected to "/templates/default/image1.jpg".

A better rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/templates/[^/]+/(.*)$ /templates/default/$1 [R]
```

Or, if you know that template directories can only have alpha-numerical characters, the underscore or the hyphen, this is better still:

```
RewriteRule ^/templates/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/(.*)$ /templates/default/$1 [R]
```

Try to keep regexes as specific as possible.